# Magento2: Admin dashboard is suddenly logout some times

Tags: magento2, backend, customer-session

when I login to the admin dashboard, after some seconds admin is logged out and redirects to the login page. What is this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase session timeout limit for backend.

You can change that in your backend here

> Store > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security > Admin Session Lifetime (seconds)

Uncheck `Use system value` checkbox and add **86400** or **31536000** there and **`Save Config`**.

After changing this you can clear cache.

Hope this will help you!